# Get touch location of high priority gesture Swift UI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

When I use a high priority gesture in swift UI I am not given the touch location, how can I get such value? Why does the normal tap gesture modifier given me a CG Point for the touch location while the high priority gesture does not.

```
   .highPriorityGesture(
               TapGesture()
                   .onEnded { loc in
                       
                      // loc.x doesnt work
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `SpatialTapGesture()`, works for me.

```
 .highPriorityGesture(
     SpatialTapGesture()
         .onEnded { loc in
             print("---> loc: \(loc)")
         })
```

See also the docs at [SpatialTapGesture](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/spatialtapgesture)

Comment: Thanks for the help, can you look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77710737/swift-ui-center-image-that-is-rendered-asynchronously