# Swift UI Center Image that is rendered asynchronously

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to position an image in the center of the screen. I am using KFImage which is from the [KingFisher](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher) library to render and display images from the web. These images are not instantly rendered so the onAppear method isn't always sufficient to calculate the image size. Using 2 spacers in a VStack also doesn't work. And setting the alignment to center also doesn't work. My method below works very well for UIImages but due to the fact that the image may not be rendered when the onAppear executes, it fails sometimes. How can I center the image?

```
                     KFImage(URL(string: image))
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                            .offset(x: (screenWidth() - imageWidth) / 2.0, y: (screenHeight() - imageHeight) / 2.0)
                            .background (
                                GeometryReader { proxy in
                                    Color.clear
                                        .onAppear {
                                            imageHeight = proxy.size.height
                                            imageWidth = proxy.size.width
                                        }
                                        .onChange(of: currentStory) { _ in
                                            imageHeight = proxy.size.height
                                            imageWidth = proxy.size.width
                                        }
                                }
                            )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simplest way is to put it into ZStack, it will always center, no matter what the image's size is.

```swift
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        KFImage(url)
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
    }
}
```

The attached images below are VStack including Text and ZStack above.

[image]